# Parse Server Cloud Code Update User

Tags: javascript, parse-platform, cloud

I am attempting to update a parse user field and the function stops in the middle of it:

```
Parse.Cloud.define("modifyAdminStatus", function(request, response) {

var userQuery = new Parse.Query(Parse.User);
var isAdmin = request.params.adminStatus;
console.log("isAdmin:" + isAdmin);
userQuery.equalTo("username", request.params.username);
userQuery.find({ useMasterKey: true,
    success: function(user) {
        console.log(user.length);
        console.log("Got User")
        console.log(user);
        user.set("isAdmin", isAdmin);
        console.log("Set Status");
        user.save(null, {useMasterKey: true,
            success: function(user) {
                response.success();
            },
            error: function(error) {
                response.error(error.message);
            }
        });
    },
    error: function(error) {
        response.error(error.message);
    }
});
});
```

I dont get any syntax errors, when i run the code i get:

```
1
Got User
[ ParseUser { _objCount: 2, className: '_User', id: '2vigcitsl6' } ]
```

in my console. However, it seems to stop the code after i attempt to set the admin status. I have tried running it using useMasterKey but that didnt do anything so maybe I'm missing something and where the useMasterKey should go?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer is:

```
query.find({
... code here
});
```

Returns an array, using query.first (or selecting one object from the array) instead will get one object and allow you to set things on it.

Answer (score 0):

When you're trying to save the user,  parse expects two parameters. The first should be an object containing any changes,  and the second should be the save options.

So in your case, simply change your save to `user.save (null, {useMasterKey:true, success...})`

The way you have it now would create a column on Parse.User entitled useMasterKey, if permissions allow.

Comment: I made that change, and it still does not get past the ParseUser line from the console.

Comment: That's odd.  The only thing I can think of is the isAdmin field is expecting a different type of value you are trying to save.

Comment: Hmm no it looks right, isAdmin is a Bool and I'm attempting to set true/false on it I just checked all that to be sure.